# Log4j 2.5 PatternLayout Nano timestamp does not work

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I am using PatternLayout in log4j 2.5. I want to log also nanosec timestamps.

```
<Appenders>        
 <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="nanotimestamp = %nano %n"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>
```

And java code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for(int = 0; i< 4; i++){
        logger.info("Hi");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

And result is:

```
nanotimestamp = 0 
nanotimestamp = 0 
nanotimestamp = 0 
nanotimestamp = 0
```

Why is timestamp equal 0? How can I get the nanosec timestamp? Thanks.

Comment: Could you try with `%N` instead of `%nano`?

Comment: I will take a look. Would you mind creating a ticket for this in the log4j 2 Jira issue tracker?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue and created [LOG4J2-1248](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1248).

Comment: Fixed in master. Please verify and close.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in log4j 2.5.

Thanks for raising this. I [fixed it](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1248) and the fix will be in the 2.5.1 release.